# I cannot sync time with Microsoft Authentication app

Tags: authentication, 2fa, microsoft-authenticator

I can not log in with 2FA from Microsoft Authenticator. Although the time is correct on my Android phone, when I use the authenticator app, I can not log in to my sites. It displays the wrong code. How to fix this?

I tried to set my phone date/time to automatic but the problem remains.

I googled and find on the search there is an option to sync time inside Microsoft Authenticator, but I can not find this option in the settings menu.

Comment: Do you live in a country with a recent timezone/DST change?

Comment: @AndrewT. yes this caused problems with other software as well

Comment: Ah... if that's the case, then I believe you have to set the time manually ignoring the automatic time, [until your device receives the time zone data update (if applicable)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225186/44325).

Comment: @AndrewT.I set time manually but I dont know how to use the link you provided. Can you write this as answer with steps ? I have Android 10

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft removed that option from the Authenticator app with an update nearly 5 years ago. Using a local time should work without any issue. If your phone time is synced with the internet, the app will work correctly.

> - Microsoft Authenticator, wrong code issue, comes up if you have both 2FA and authenticator app enabled for an account.
> - **You must delete all the accounts added to the app and re-add them to fix this.**

[Read this for more](https://windowsreport.com/microsoft-authenticator-wrong-code/#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Authenticator%2C%20wrong%20code%20issue,read%20them%20to%20fix%20this.).

---

*If they still don't work:*

1. Check if you have an authenticator working on any other device, compare the time.
2. Try setting the time to the time zone you used to use earlier.
3. Or as always, clear cache, app data/reinstall, and reboot. Try again.

Comment: Thanks, tried all these methods but did not work. I tried now to use another app called authey and when I open the app it display message that time not synced but still work and I was able to login with 2FA. I have many accounts use Microsoft Authenticator , it is a big problem. When I set time to auto it display the wrong time and this also did not work.

Comment: Hmm.. that's oddly strange. Did you try removing and re-adding accounts? It worked for me the last time I had this issue. Also can you try logging in on any other device? There shouldn't be anything apart from these, make sure you are doing things correctly :)

Comment: yes I tried remove and add accounts . I tried now to use on another device but this device has Android 7 so it display this app can not be installed on this device